# what would be the best way to parallelize multiple similar program instances in shell?

Tags: shell, unix, testing, parallel-processing

I have a program that runs a test, which takes many parameters. Let's say I have the program `main.sh` that calls the `test.sh`, which is the test program. In the `main.sh`, I put in many different parameters for `test.sh` to run with. There is no problem for running only one test.

However, shell allows me to use `&` to run multiple instances at the same time. I am thinking of using a for loop to call this test multiple times with `&` (background run) with different parameters set up in the beginning of the loop. It looks like the following:

```
#main.sh
for i in 0 1 2 3; do
    value=${param[$i]}
    #test.sh takes "value" as a parameter inside it and run
    . ./test.sh &
done
```

However, `test.sh` usually take a while to finish and would use the parameter value several times. In this case, when the loop keeps running and increments "`i`" that changes the parameter value, the initial instance of `test.sh` will then take different parameter and the loop keeps on going. Is there a way to make `test.sh` run with a unchanging parameter value for any program instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You child script `test.sh` will have a *copy* of the parent's environment, so changing the parent data in the parent will not affect it (as long as you run it as a *child* process, *not* via dot operator). You can do it two ways:

- Passing the parameter in the command line of `test.sh`
- Exporting an environment variable prior to starting `test.sh`

In either case this will not affect instances of `test.sh` that you started earlier.

More specifically, try:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    value=${param[$i]}
    ./test.sh $value &    # value is passed as command-line parameter
done
```

Comment: Hi Alex, what I wrote was just an example, there are a LOT of variables to be passed in. I can't pass them by command-line argument. Can you explain your phrase "as long as you run it as a child process, not via dot operator"? And how would you run test.sh? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a lot of variables, why don't you `export` them prior to invoking your child script. As for the dot command (which is a shorthand for `source` command), I am not sure it supports running things in background. It basically instructs your current shell to read lines from its argument and interpret them in it's _current_ environment.

Comment: If I export the environment variables, the next iteration of the loop comes so fast that these variables changed again in the middle of the execution of the child script... what to do with this?

Comment: That's not how it works. The `&` operation effectively makes a `fork()` system call which clones the current process (along with it's environment). Your parent process is guaranteed to continue it's operation _after_ cloning has been done (note, that it doesn't mean that the child process has started running by that time). So you cannot affect the child environment once `fork()` returns.